# Not able to click a button on Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am not able to click Not able to click Button(element) on Selenium webdriver.

**HTML TAG**

```
<button class="btn-secondary ml-05" test-id="MODULE1A_BUTTON">Without Optimisation</button>
```

**Java Code**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//Button[@test-id ='MODULE1A_BUTTON' ]")).click();
```

Comment: HTML tag: <button class="btn-secondary ml-05" test-id="MODULE1A_BUTTON">Without Optimisation</button>

Comment: Welcome to SO please edit your question with more detail like url and  web element

Answer (score 0):

Try to click it with js executor as below:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//Button[@test-id ='MODULE1A_BUTTON' ]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```